# uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce

```
environment.rb:7: uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:39
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I'm getting the preceding error, I'm trying to integrate salesforce with a rails app following the PDF here: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/02/a-brief-history-of-ruby-rails-with-the-forcecom-platform.html

I have made the instructions required, however it is required to edit the `environment.rb`
Here is my current version:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Newsletter::Application.initialize!

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem "asf-soap-adapter", :lib => "activerecord-activesalesforce-adapter"
  config.gem "asf-soap-adapter", :lib => 'asf-soap-adapter'
  config.database_configuration_file = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config','salesforce.yml')
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the new Gem 'databasedotcom' for the same purpose which works perfectly
http://richardvanhook.github.com/databasedotcom-guide/#create_a_databasecom_account

Answer (score 3):

I assume based on your tag that you are working in a Rails 3 app, the issue you have is that the environment.rb you have is Rails 2 specific. In Rails 3 you should be specifying your gems in your Gemfile, and removing the Rails::Initializer from your environment.rb.

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'asf-soap-adapter', :require =>'activerecord-activesalesforce-adapter'
```

There are some notes here on the upgrade from Rails 2 -> Rails 3.

http://rails3.community-tracker.com/permalinks/5/notes-from-the-field-upgrading-to-rails-3